# AsyncTask Loader with oritentation

Tags: android

I just started using AsyncTask Loader, thing is when orientation changes happens ,if a task that about to complete,gets started again from the start.I can solve this above problem with asynctask and headless fragment.
I have posted the code below.I just want to avoid to load again complete data instead continue what already cached before changing orientation.
I may have missed some points in reading Docs, please just bear with me

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, MainActivity.this).forceLoad();

}

@Override
public Loader<List<String>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    SampleLoader loader = new SampleLoader(MainActivity.this);
    Log.w(TAG, "onCreateLoader()");
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<String>> loader, List<String> list) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onLoadFinished()");
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    stopLoader();

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<String>> loader) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onLoaderReset()");
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(null);
}

private static class SampleLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<String>> {
    public SampleLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> loadInBackground() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadInBackGround()");

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            list.add(animals[i]);
            System.out.println("sleep : " + i);
            SystemClock.sleep(300);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

private void stopLoader() {
    Log.e(TAG, "stopLoader()");
    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(LOADER_ID);
}
```

//current output : 1
2
3
4
...
14 //screen rotation 
15
16
..24 
//again starts with 1 -24 then shows results

Comment: Consider using ViewModel approach for orientation changes

Comment: @okset, bit new to android

Comment: why are you calling forceLoad() and stopLoader() ?

Answer (score -1):

you need to put

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your `<Activity>` tag to avoid changes when orientation is changed.

Comment: this is not hack @Avinash

Comment: @jigarsavaliya yes it is a hack ...  from docs: *android:configChanges ... Using this attribute **should be avoided** and used only as a last resort.*